# Kotlin Fragment : Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, kotlin

I use Intent.ACTION_PICK to take picture from gallery.
I already success when implement both activity, but found problem when using fragment.
I need some help, please.

Here MainActivity.kt

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            when (requestCode) {
                REQUEST_NEW_CHAT -> {
                    val name: String = data?.getStringExtra(PARAM_NAME) ?: ""
                    val phone: String = data?.getStringExtra(PARAM_PHONE) ?: ""
                    checkNewChatUser(name, phone)
                }
                //TODO: I.5. Update Status Page
                REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO -> statusUpdateFragment?.storeImage(data?.data)
            }
        }
    }
```

Here StatusUpdateFragment.kt

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        lay_progressbar.setOnTouchListener { v, event -> true }
        btn_status.setOnClickListener { onUpdate() }
        populateImage(context, imageUrl, img_status)

        lay_status.setOnClickListener{
            if(isAdded){
                (activity as MainActivity).startNewActivity(REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO)
            }
        }
    }

    fun storeImage(imageUri: Uri?) {
        if (imageUri != null && userId != null) {
            //error message : Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
            try {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Uploading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    lay_progressbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            catch (e:Exception){
                e.message
            }

            /*more code that i hide it...*/
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where you init statusUpdateFragment?

Comment: i write in MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), FailureCallback {
...
private val statusUpdateFragment = StatusUpdateFragment()
...
```

Comment: I mean where you commit it? by Fragment Transaction or XML? or Navigation?

Comment: by XML.fragment_status_update.xml

Comment: No I mean when you add your fragment to show in Activity?

Answer (score 0):

Alhamdulillah, i already solved by Fahru.

MainActivity.kt : must add this at onActivityResult

```
   override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            when (requestCode) {
                REQUEST_NEW_CHAT -> {
                    val name: String = data?.getStringExtra(PARAM_NAME) ?: ""
                    val phone: String = data?.getStringExtra(PARAM_PHONE) ?: ""
                    checkNewChatUser(name, phone)
                }
                //TODO: I.5. Update Status Page
                REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO -> statusUpdateFragment?.storeImage(data?.data,this)
            }
        }
    }
```

StatusUpdateFragment.kt : must add context at storeImage

````
```
fun storeImage(imageUri: Uri?, context: Context) {
    if (imageUri != null && userId != null) {
        try {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Uploading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                lay_progressbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
        catch (e:Exception){
            e.message
        }

    //more code hidden
}
```
````